# Connot save link to secondary drive on desktop 19.04

Tags: hard-drive

Until 19.04 i had a link to my secondary drive located on the desktop, now there seems to be no way to save such a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desktop icons work differently in 19.04, due to changes in GNOME Shell. It's still a work-in-progress.

Most individual icons no longer work. Folders do. Create a desktop folder called `Work in Progress`... or `pseudo Desktop`... and create/move your symbolic link INSIDE the new folder. It'll work there.

Comment: thanks for the lead, i made the symlink in Home folder and copy/pasted it to desktop, now works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try **ln** command to make symbolic link to your secondary drive.

You can then directly jump to your secondary drive from your Desktop

Comment: This won't work in 19.04

Comment: @heynnema I can make links in Desktop just fine.
Can you please elaborate so I can understand too. Thnx :)

Comment: In the recent GNOME Shell, 3.23?, they removed the desktop functionality. The temporary workaround was to create the GNOME Shell extension `Desktop Icons`. This new extension only provides for the barest minimum in desktop functionality. Hence, the nice smattering of desktop icons that we all used to have on our desktop for easy access... most stopped working... unless they're dropped into a folder on the desktop. Also, you can no longer just drag-and-drop individual files on the Desktop, without using `Files` (Navigator) to do so.